# HTML table with a variable amount of rows

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, sweetalert2

I have an array with a variable amount of rows that I'm trying to create a table of. The table will be inside a popup window (SweetAlert), and the rows come from an AJAX call that is grabbing a PHP database query. The query is sent over and is viewable with console.log, but I don't know how to format the  and  to loop as many times as needed, preferably with just the html and js.

```
$.ajax({
                    url:"../model/test.php",
                    data: {'order-startDate': startDate, 'order-endDate' : endDate, 'order-custId' : custId},
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(result){
                        result = JSON.parse(result);
                        console.log(result);
                        
                        Swal.fire({
                            html: `<p><h5>` + custId + `</h5></p><br>` + startDate + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + endDate + `<br>
                            <table class="table-datatable display responsive nowrap table-bordered table-striped">
                            <tbody>`,
                            //This is the idea of what I'm trying to accomplish
                            for (let index = 0; index < result.length; ++index)
                            {
                                `<tr>
                                    <td>` + result[index]['item'] + `</td>
                                    <td>`+result[index]['count']+`</td>
                                </tr>`
                            }
                            `</tbody>
                            </table>`
                        })
                    }
                })
```

There are only two columns in the db call/table. I can probably get the length just fine, just not sure how to create it all in the html portion of the Swal.fire() call.

Comment: A for loop in that place makes little sense, that is not even valid syntax. Assemble your HTML code in a variable, before you call `Swal.fire` - and then pass that variable to the method.

Comment: @CBroe As soon as I posted I got the idea to just make a string and pass that. Goes to show that just explaining what you want to do to yourself can solve an issue you've been trying for a while. Works perfectly. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have properly *"assembled"* your code. Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url:"../model/test.php",
    data: {'order-startDate': startDate, 'order-endDate' : endDate, 'order-custId' : custId},
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(result){
        result = JSON.parse(result);
        console.log(result);
        
        // create the result as array of rows
        let rows = result.map(obj => `<tr><td>${obj.item}</td><td>${obj.count}</td></tr>`);

        Swal.fire({
            html: `<p><h5>${custId}</h5></p><br>${startDate}&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;${endDate}<br>
            <table class="table-datatable display responsive nowrap table-bordered table-striped">
                <tbody>
                    ${rows.join('')}
                </tbody>
            </table>`
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: That's very similar to what I just got working, but your way looks much cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The question is already answered so instead of answering I'll leave a similar scenario that uses the same logic to display data but this one is from an API call since from the OP code there's no way to view how to handle actually data result.

```js
//I can't make an AJAX call to your data source (`test.php`) so instead I'll make an API call and display the data in a table on a SweetAlert popup
$( document ).ready(function() {
var tableRows = '';
  $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.covid19api.com/summary',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(result){
            for(let i = 0; i < result.Countries.length; i++){
               tableRows += '<tr><td>'+result.Countries[i]['Country']+'</td><td>'+result.Countries[i]['TotalConfirmed']+'</td></tr>';
            }
            
            
            
            Swal.fire({
  title: '<strong><u>Covid Cases Per Country</u></strong><br/>',
  icon: 'info',
  html: '<table class="table-datatable display responsive nowrap table-bordered table-striped w-100">' +
        '<thead><th>Country</th><th>Covid-19 Cases</th></thead>' +
        '<tbody class="table-body">' +
        
        '</tbody>' +
         '</table>'
})

        $('.table-body').html(tableRows);
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11.4.0/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to make a string with the html in it in the javascript section, if anyone else comes across the same question.

```
$.ajax({
                    url:"../model/test.php",
                    data: {'order-startDate': startDate, 'order-endDate' : endDate, 'order-custId' : custId},
                    type: 'GET',
                    success: function(result){
                        result = JSON.parse(result);
                        console.log(result);
                        let input = "";
                        for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
                            input += `<td>` + result[i]['item_sku'] + `</td><td>`+result[0]['count']+`</td>`;
                        Swal.fire({
                            html: `<p><h5>` + custId + `</h5></p><br>` + startDate + `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` + endDate + `<br>
                            <table class="table-datatable display responsive nowrap table-bordered table-striped">
                            <tbody>
                                ` + input + `
                            </tbody>
                            </table>`
                        })
                    }
                })
```